# Unable to live boot most Linux distros on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtual-host

The host OS is Windows 7 and the machine supports virtualization which I have enabled in BIOS. (I can confirm it works because without virtualization enabled in BIOS VBox does not show 64 bit OS versions as guest options). I loaded various Linux ISO's into MagicDisc and added the virtual DVD drives to the virtual machine storage tree. There are no other devices plugged.

When I try to start up the virtual machine with Ubuntu, it starts booting up with the purple (or is it violet?) screen and I get a kernel panic soon after. When I try Debian, it starts installing and when it is time to load the packages it stops being able to find the same CD from which it booted. When I try CentOS, I have the same trouble as Ubuntu (kernel panic shortly after the bootup screen). The only thing that worked was one of the very minimal distros (tiny core). Has anyone any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loading the isos into a virtual drive and trying to boot from that, have you tried just pointing the VirtualBox boot device to the iso file?

[AskUbuntu has the steps for that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64915/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-virtualbox-client-from-an-iso-image)